# how can I resolve this gemfile conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, locomotivecms, excon

I'm getting this error after `bundle install`. How can I fix it?

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "excon":
  In Gemfile:
    locomotive-heroku (~> 0.0.2) ruby depends on
      excon (~> 0.9.4) ruby

    excon (0.20.0)
```

Comment: From the error it looks like that `locomotive-heroku` depends on `excon 0.9.4` but you have `excon (0.20.0)` have you you could do `gem  uni` which will list what versions of `excon` you have installed, as there must be some conflict. Further to this I believe that this conflict can occur due to the `Gemfile.lock` have a look in there please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by putting the locations for the current repos for locomotive/engine and locomotive/heroku. I.e gem 'locomotive-heroku', git: 'repolocation', require: 'locomotive/heroku' This is also what eventually got me a working installation of locomotivecms on heroku. I did need to set it to compile assets in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the latest version of the gem: `gem uninstall excon -v=0.20.0`. Then bundle install again to see if it resolved the problem.

Comment: didn't work. can i fork locomotive-heroku on github and edit it so that it requires excon (~> 0.14)? I don't know how...

Comment: After removing the 0.20.0 version, when you type a `gem list | grep excon`, did it show you the 0.9.4 one?